# How to enable TablePress content in search result Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, seo

I have a website with hundreds of articles and hundreds of table (tablepress).

The website is using Ocean WP theme and both default search and search and filter extension.

In the search results there is no result if i am searching for something that is in a table which is in a post.

It should be found, so i don't understand why i have no result.

For exemple, i have a post named 'Stackoverflow' and in this article there is a table in which there is the Wordpress name.

i wish i could find this article by searching the Wordpress keyword.

The default behaviour should do the job or is there some code to change in a file or is there and extension that can do the job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by using Ajax search pro to include shortcode from post into my search form. It's not free but atleast it took me only 5 minutes to setup the plugin to replace my default search form.